# How to get size of a custom dialog in android?

Tags: android, dialog, size

I have a custom Dialog which is extended from dialog.
in order to place component on it, I need to know the width of the dialog. how could I do it?
Thanks

EDIT:

```
public class AnswerTypeDialog extends Dialog{
    public AnswerTypeDialog(Context context) {
        super(context);
        mContext = context;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        init();
    }

    protected void init(){
        ll=(RelativeLayout) LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.answertype_layout, null);
        this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        setContentView(ll);
        mWindowWidth = this.getWindow().getAttributes().width;
    }
}
```

mWindowWidth is zero.

Comment: its upto you what you give height width of the dialog.

Comment: @seaplain did you figure this out?

Comment: try to change the way you think. Use resource identifies and create multiple layouts based on screen size.

Answer (score 0):

This will work.

```
@Override
    public void onWindowFocusChanged (boolean hasFocus) {
        super.onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus);
        int height=mDialog.getWindow().getDecorView().getHeight();
    int width=mDialog.getWindow().getDecorView().getWidth();
}
```