# How to get dialog size?

Tags: java, android, dialog, android-dialog

I am looking for a way to get size of a custom dialog. I went through [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11392334/how-to-get-size-of-a-custom-dialog-in-android) question, but the only answer given is pretty useless, because if I try `mDialog.getWindow().getAttributes().height;` it only returns -2, which is a constant for `WRAP_CONTENT` attribute which I set to dialog. How can I get the size of it. I want to know the siye for the background image.

Comment: what dialog exactly do you use?

Comment: public class ControlOverlay extends Dialog, so just Dialog

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Actually, in Android it doesn't work like in iOS - you can't get the size of the `View` itself, what you can do, though, is to ask for the size of the **ROOT** layout of that view.

e.g.:

`myDialog.this.findViewById(R.id.dialog_root_layout).getHeight());`

Comment: Although it returns the size of the dialog without a header, it is exactly what I needed.

Comment: @Michal: I get `dialog_root_layout cannot be resolved or is not a field` for an `AlertDialog`.

Comment: @LuisA.Florit Instead of putting dialog_root_layout you should insert ID of your dialog.

Comment: @Michal: Ooops, now I understand what you meant. However, I had some problems with your suggestion: First, I get an error `myDialog cannot be resolved to a type`. Second, myDialog is created with a `final AlertDialog myDialog = builder.create()`, and there is no `setID` method for an `AlertDialog`, so how do I get its root layout ID? Thanks!

Answer (score 22):

Give it a try after the dialog will be showed:

```
mDialog.getWindow().getDecorView().getHeight()
```

Comment: Great works really well, Michal's answer is better for my case though.

Comment: @KorniltsevAnatoly: This doesn't work for me. I get 0.

Comment: @Override
 public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus) {
  super.onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus);
  //call here
 }

Comment: @LuisA.Florit you need to use it after the dialog will be showed

Answer (score 7):

@Kormilsev Anatoliy has answered correct and I am just improving.
So in the class you inherit from Dialog class  just override the method:

```
@Override
public void onWindowFocusChanged (boolean hasFocus) {
    super.onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus);
    height = getWindow().getDecorView().getHeight();
}
```

Comment: and how to set this event for AlertDialog??

Comment: this `alertDialog.setOnShowListener(new DialogInterface.OnShowListener()` will work

Comment: Yes. This is a decision  for mostly used AlertDialogs.

Comment: @user924 Oh my god, finally something in here that worked

Comment: 'Code to life'  It sounds so good. Thanks for your awesome coding.

Answer (score 5):

In case, if you have your own XML layouts for custom dialog.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/dialog_main_layout"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:background="@color/primaryBackground">

    /* whatever you want here */

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

In activity:

```
    final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(this);
    dialog.setContentView(R.layout.popup_gameover);

    dialog.setOnShowListener(new DialogInterface.OnShowListener() {
        @Override
        public void onShow(DialogInterface d) {
            View view = dialog.findViewById(R.id.dialog_main_layout);
            int width = view.getWidth();
            int height = view.getHeight();

            ...
        }
    });
```

This `width` and `height` exacly as expected.